# add custom commandbar menu to a specific excel table using c#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I have a custom commandbar menu in table right-click, but i need this to be specific to one table and do not want it to show on any other tables. Is this possible at all?
if not, any alternative suggestions?

```
    editSourceBtn = (Office.CommandBarButton)tableCommandBar.Controls.Add(1, missing, missing, missing, missing);
    editSourceBtn.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
    editSourceBtn.Caption = "Edit Source";
    editSourceBtn.Tag = "Edit Source";
    editSourceBtn.Click +=new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(editSourceBtn_Click);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I had one table in one specific tab and wanted the right click context for that, where i specify it in the if statement if the sheet is the one i need and the selected range intersects with the table range it adds the right click button.

```
private void Application_SheetBeforeRightClick(object Sh, Excel.Range Target, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Excel.Range ResourceTable;
        Excel.Range IntersectRange;

        foreach (Office.CommandBarControl ctrl in tableCommandBar.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.Tag == "Edit" || ctrl.Tag == "Delete") ctrl.Delete();
        }
        editBtn = null;

        if (this.Application.ActiveSheet.Name == "Mysheet" && this.Application.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Count > 0)  
        {

            ResourceTable = this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets["Mysheet"].ListObjects["myTable"].Range;
            IntersectRange = this.Application.Intersect(ResourceTable, Target);

            if (IntersectRange != null & ResourceTable.Rows.Count > 2 && editSourceBtn == null)
            {
                editBtn = (Office.CommandBarButton)tableCommandBar.Controls.Add(1, missing, missing, missing, missing);
                editBtn.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
                editBtn.Tag = "Edit";
                editBtn.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(editSourceBtn_Click);

            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But that fact is that command bars are not used any longer. They were deprecated. You need to use Fluent UI controls instead. You can use a callback, for example, getEnabled or getVisible, and when required you may call the [Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidate%28v=office.14%29.aspx) or InvalidateControl method of the IRibbonUI interface to get your callbacks invoked.

```
Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI
Sub MyAddInInitialize(Ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set MyRibbon = Ribbon
End Sub
Sub myFunction()
    // Invalidates the caches of all of this add-in’s controls 
    MyRibbon.Invalidate()            
End Sub
```

You can read more about the Ribbon UI in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: This adds a button to the ribbon, and i was trying to avoid it because this button will be used only for one table in the whole workbook, that is why i thought adding a button to right click menu is more suitable.